# How to wait for each process to terminate in the following example?

Tags: c, linux, fork, wait

The program terminates after taking 4 or 5 values from `scanf`.
But I want it to accept 8 values (totaling 8 processes) and then terminate.

```
void main() {
    fork();
    fork();
    fork();

    scanf("%d",&j);
    printf("The values are %d\n",j);

    wait(0);
}
```

Comment: How are you running the program and what makes you think that only four or five values are accepted? Note that if stdin is redirected to a pipe, it is likely that the first process to call scanf will drain the pipe and the remaining processes will see EOF.

Comment: @rici, not likely. Each process does a `scanf(3)` on the file descriptor (with the added condition that the file is `dup(2)`ed and reads are sequential on it)  The problem here is that when the process group leader dies(whatever position it got in the reading queue), the remaining processes are killed by the kernel.

Comment: Just tested and the kernel does not kill the processes.  But they get `EOF` from the input descriptor once the group leader dies.  Sorry, but with the testings I couldn't edit my last comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the first question you have to answer to yourself is **how many processes you think you have there?**  As you don't use the returned value from the `fork(2)` system call, you don't know even if you are the parent or you are the child after execution of each fork.

You'll have one process at the beginning of the tale, which does a `fork(2)` system call and converts in **two** processes, that then execute (both, parent and child) a second `fork(2)` call, converting (each) in two processes (two more, so four in total) when the second call returns.  Then comes the third, which duplicates again the number of processes, so you'll get at the end of the story **eight** running processes at all in a binary tree execution history hierarchy fully populated up to height three.

## but the processes relationships are not the same

The processes can each `wait(2)` for each of their **own** children, but *there are processes that, **since their inceptions** have made three, two, one, or no `fork()` at all*. The root node is the only that makes three `fork()`s, so it can do up to three `wait(2)`s without error (for each of its children), the first of its children, makes only two, the second makes only one... like this:

```
proc[0]---fork()-----fork()---fork()----exit();
          |          |        |
          |          |        proc[3]---exit();
          |          |       
          |          proc[2]--fork()----exit();
          |                   |
          |                   proc[4]---exit();
          |
          proc[1]----fork()---fork()----exit();
                     |        |
                     |        proc[5]---exit();
                     |
                     proc[6]--fork()----exit();
                              |
                              proc[7]---exit();
```

so

- `proc[0]` can `wait(2)` to `proc[1]`, `proc[2]` and `proc[3]`;
- `proc[1]` can `wait(2)` to `proc[5]` and `proc[6]`;
- `proc[2]` can `wait(2)` to `proc[4]` only
- `proc[3]` cannot `wait(2)` (it will result in error if `wait(2)` is called);
- `proc[4]` cannot `wait(2)`;
- `proc[5]` cannot `wait(2)`;
- `proc[6]` can `wait(2)` only to `proc[7]` and
- `proc[7]` cannot `wait(2)`.

As `wait(2)` can only wait for one of such children (children must be created with fork, or the call will result in error) you have to issue as many `wait(2)` calls as *`fork(2)`s you have issued*, to wait for them all, so you must control the number of children you have (as you see, this number is different for each process).  You can, for example, increment a counter *in the parent* (the process that receives a `0` result from `fork(2)` so you know the number of `fork(2)`s you have issued up to now.

```
int main()
{
    int forks_made = 0;
    if (fork() > 0) forks_made++;
    if (fork() > 0) forks_made++;
    if (fork() > 0) forks_made++;
    for (i = 0; i < forks_made; i++) wait(NULL);
    exit(0);
}
```

or simply, you can `wait(2)` until the system call results in an error (you don't have more children)

```
int main()
{
    fork();
    fork();
    fork();
    while(wait(NULL) == 0) 
        continue;
    exit(0);
}
```

Be careful as the process hierarchy is a different tree from the binary **history** tree.  The process hierarchy is like this:

```
proc[0]
|
+--proc[1]
|  |
|  +--proc[5]
|  |
|  `--proc[6]
|     |
|     `--proc[7]
|
+--proc[2]
|  |
|  `--proc[4]
|
`--proc[3]
```

Suppose I write the following code:

```
int main()
{
    fork(); fork(); fork();
    wait(0); wait(0); wait(0);
    exit(0);
}
```

The result is:

```
                                ok             ok         ok
p[0]-f()-f()-f()----------------w()------------w()--------w()-exit();
     |   |   |                  ^              ^          ^
     |   |   |      err err err |              |          |
     |   |   +-p[3]-w()-w()-w()-exit();        |          |
     |   |                                     |          |
     |   |                         ok  err err |          |
     |   +-p[2]-f()----------------w()-w()-w()-exit();    |
     |          |                  ^                      |
     |          |                  |                      |
     |          |      err err err |                      |
     |          +-p[4]-w()-w()-w()-exit();                |
     |                             ok             ok  err |
     +-p[1]-f()-f()----------------w()------------w()-w()-exit();
            |   |                  ^              ^
            |   |      err err err |              |
            |   +-p[5]-w()-w()-w()-exit();        |
            |                         ok  err err |
            +-p[6]-f()----------------w()-w()-w()-exit();
                   |                  ^
                   |      err err err |
                   +-p[7]-w()-w()-w()-exit();
```

## NOTE

Even if the children die *before* the parent does a `wait(2)` the kernel maintains them in the process table (but without any resource allocated) as *zombie processes* just to wait for the parent to do the proper `wait(2)` system call.  This is why the kernel knows that you can do a `wait(2)` or not (you can only wait if you have made a `fork(2)`).

## NOTE 2

Why the process only `read(2)`s part of the results and finishes? Well, I have been reading some documentation and making some tests, and the behaviours are different on the three operating systems I have tested on:

- MacOS X.  I have tested and when the process group leader `exit(2)`s, all of its children are awaken from the `read(2)` call and given a `ETIMEDOUT` error (surprisingly)
- FreeBSD. On FreeBSD, the result is similar but with a different error (`EIO`).
- Linux. On Linux, the terminal driver gives each process only one input character (even if there are more) in raw mode (they output each caracter as it is read) This is by far the most weird behaviour.

As normal job control makes the shell to reacquire the control terminal and the process group ceases to be the control group of the terminal device, the terminal should awake all the processes trying to `read(2)` from it with an error code, so perhaps FreeBSD is the most coherent result we should have.

The code used to test this case follows:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

void hndlr(int sig)
{
    printf("%d(prnt=%d,pgrp=%d): signal %d received\n",
            getpid(), getppid(), getpgrp(), sig);
}

int main()
{
    int i;
    char line[1024];

    for (i = 1; i < 64; i++)
        signal(i, hndlr);
    printf("pid=%d, pgrp=%d\n", getpid(), getpgrp());
    fork();
    fork();
    fork();
    i = read(0, line, sizeof line);
    switch(i) {
    case -1:
        printf("pid=%d, prnt=%d, pgrp=%d: read: %s(errno=%d)\n",
                getpid(), getppid(), getpgrp(), strerror(errno), errno);
        break;
    case 0:
        printf("pid=%d, prnt=%d, pgrp=%d: read: EOF\n",
                getpid(), getppid(), getpgrp());
        break;
    default:
        printf("pid=%d, prnt=%d, pgrp=%d: read: [%*.*s]\n",
                getpid(), getppid(), getpgrp(), i, i, line);
        break;
    }
#if 0
    wait(NULL);
    wait(NULL);
    wait(NULL);
#endif
} /* main */
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that `wait(0)` only waits for the first child. The main process will exit once it has successfully raced to get its own input, and a direct child has done the same.

The easiest kludge is to just wait until there are no more children to wait for:

```
void main() {
    int j;
    fork();
    fork();
    fork();

    scanf("%d", &j);
    printf("The values are %d\n",j);

    while (wait(0) != -1);
}
```

This reads 8 values from the interactive terminal as expected.

You should never do this in a real program though. The main thread should instead read all 8 values and create the children as needed to process them. Failing to do so causes race conditions and buffering issues.

Here's an example of this, using one less `fork()` for brevity:

```
$ for i in {1..4}; do echo "$i"; done  | ./foo
The values are 1
The values are 0
The values are 0
The values are 0

$ for i in {1..4}; do echo "$i"; sleep 0.1; done  | ./foo
The values are 1
The values are 2
The values are 3
The values are 4
```

In the former case, multiple writes to the pipe become a single read, which is picked up by an arbitrary process. The others get nothing.

In the second case, a short sleep is added to allow more time between each read, and now they get the values as expected.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. My requirement is such that I should be monitoring for all 8 Scanf's. And whichever comes out of blocking state should process them. With multiple copies of j being made, I am not sure how there will be race condition. Please elaborate your approach if you were to do it differently.

Comment: I added an example. The better way to do this is `for(int i=0; i<8; i++) { scanf("%d", &j); if(!fork()) process(j); }` , so that only one process reads from stdin at a time.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wait for all your children and your children need to wait for their children, etc. Currently your `wait(0)` call only waits for one child to change state.

```
// wait(0); 
while (1) {
   int status;
   pid_t done = wait( &status );
   if ( done == -1 )
      break; // no more children
}
```