# Understanding how UNIX fork() affects parent process

Tags: c, unix, fork

I have the following program that uses the fork() function to create child processes

```
#include <stdio.h>
   int main (){
   printf("PID:%d\n",getpid());//print1:P1
   fork();
   fork();
   fork();
   printf ("Done"); //print2:P2
}
```

I am trying to understand how does the above program prints 'Done' 8 times because that the output.

Comment: You have one parent process. First `fork()` creates one child process. Second `fork()` is executed by both, parent and child process, so you create two additional processes and so on.

Comment: "...the above program prints 'Done' 8 times..."  - *WRONG*!  The above program prints 'Done' *ONCE*.  The children each print 'Done' once ... *TO THE SAME CONSOLE* ("StdOut").   Your child processes also create children: the first child: two children, the second child, one.  And their children create children.  Hence "8", altogether.

Comment: @paulsm4 Jee, calm down on the caps and italics.

Comment: One other point - the *ONLY* way a child [fork()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html) affects the parent is that it returns the child's PID to the parent.  Which you aren't using anyway :(

Comment: You could track what's going on better by using `int pid1 = fork(); int pid2 = fork(); int pid3 = fork();` to capture the return values from `fork()` and then print all the information: `printf("Done: PID = %d, PPID = %d, pid1 = %d, pid2 = %d, pid3 = %d\n", (int)getpid(), (int)getppid(), pid1, pid2, pid3);`.  Properly interpreted, this will make what goes on much clearer — you'll know which process printed each line of output.  (The only issue might be interlaced printing between separate processes; that's harder to fix if it becomes a routine problem.)

Comment: Check [this response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38749152/how-to-wait-for-each-process-to-terminate-in-the-following-example/38786600#38786600).  It shows the process tree you build.

Answer (score 3):

You should note that each subsequent fork will get executed by children that created before. So the process hierarchy will be as follows:

```
Parent
  -- Child 1                   (first fork executed by Parent)
     -- Grandchild 1           (second fork executed by Child 1)
        -- Grand-grandchild 1  (third fork executed by Grandchild 1)
     -- Grandchild 2           (third fork executed by Child 1)
  -- Child 2                   (second fork executed by Parent)
     -- Grandchild 3           (third fork executed by Child 2)
  -- Child 3                   (third fork executed by Parent)
```

And each of these will call `printf ("Done");`. 8 in total.

Answer (score 1):

When a process is created by calling `fork()` like

```
 fork();
```

After `fork()` whatever statements are there, once they executed by child & once by parent process. In your case `fork()` is called thrice hence it print 8 times `Done`. It looks like

```
fork();
printf ("Done\n"); /* once printed by child process & once by parent process, so for one fork() call, it prints 2 times Done. For 3 fork call, 8 times */
```

From the manual page of `fork()`

> `fork()`  creates  a **new process** by **duplicating** the **calling
>   process**.  The
>          new process, referred to as the child, is an  exact  duplicate  of  the
>          calling  process

Answer (score 0):

I'll make it a bit more visual:

## Step 1

```
// Program 1
#include <stdio.h>
   int main (){
   printf("PID:%d\n",getpid());//print1:P1
   fork(); // <- Current Line
   fork();
   fork();
   printf ("Done"); //print2:P2
}
```

## Step 2

When this line executes, it splits into two programs:

```
// Program 1                                                   >----|
#include <stdio.h>                                                  |
   int main (){                                                     |
   printf("PID:%d\n",getpid());//print1:P1                          |
   fork(); // Returns child's PID [Program 1 Version 2]             |
   fork(); // <- Current line                                       |
   fork();                                                          |
   printf ("Done"); //print2:P2                                     |
}                                                                   |
                                                                    |
// Program 1 Version 2 (Child of Program 1)   >----|                |
#include <stdio.h>                                 |                |
   int main (){                                    |                |
   printf("PID:%d\n",getpid());//print1:P1         |                |
   fork(); // Returns 0, since it's a child        |                |
   fork(); // <- Current line                      |                |
   fork();                                         |                |
   printf ("Done"); //print2:P2                    |                |
}                                                  |                |
```

## Step 3

When Program 1 Version 2 executes its current line, it creates

```
// Program 1 Version 2                       <-----|                |
#include <stdio.h>                                 |                |
   int main (){                                    |                |
   printf("PID:%d\n",getpid());//print1:P1         |                |
   fork();                                         |                |
   fork(); // Returns child's PID [Program 1 Version 2] Version 2   |
   fork(); // <- Current line                      |                |
   printf ("Done"); //print2:P2                    |                |
}                                                  |                |
                                              v----|                |
// [Program 1 Version 2] Version 2 (Child of Program 1 Version 2)   |
#include <stdio.h>                                                  |
   int main (){                                                     |
   printf("PID:%d\n",getpid());//print1:P1                          |
   fork();                                                          |
   fork(); // Returns 0 (It's a new child)                          |
   fork(); // <- Current line                                       |
   printf ("Done"); //print2:P2                                     |
}                                                                   |
```

When Program 1 executes its current line, it creates

```
// Program 1                                           <------------|
#include <stdio.h>                                                  |
   int main (){                                                     |
   printf("PID:%d\n",getpid());//print1:P1                          |
   fork();                                                          |
   fork(); // Returns child's PID [Program 1 Version 3]             |
   fork(); // <- Current line                                       |
   printf ("Done"); //print2:P2                                     |
}                                                                   |
                                                                    |
// Program 1 Version 3 (Child of Program 1)             <-----------|
#include <stdio.h>
   int main (){
   printf("PID:%d\n",getpid());//print1:P1
   fork();
   fork(); // Returns 0 (Is a new child)
   fork(); // <- Current line
   printf ("Done"); //print2:P2
}
```

## Step 4

Each of the final forks again duplicates each program, leaving you with 8 programs running. Each original program gets the child's PID as returned by fork. Each child program gets 0. Then they all `printf("Done")`

### Note

Once a program is generated, it just runs all the forks and gets a bunch of PIDs, then prints done. It just happens that each fork makes a child, but the parent doesn't notice and they're basically NO-OPs for the parent.